# How to replace comma separated department ids with their name respectively?

Tags: mysql, join

My tables are these :

Employee Table:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| id       | name     | department  |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1        | Carrera  | 1           |
| 2        | Taylor   | 1,2         |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Department Table:

```
+--------+-------+
| id     | name  |
+--------+-------+
|   1    |  CS   |
|   2    |  IT   |
+--------+-------+
```

Wanted output from employee table and department table :

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | name       | department  |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 | Carrera    |   CS        |
|  2 | Taylor     |   CS,IT     |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Dont do it. Create another table `employee_department(employee_id, department_id)` to link the two tables together.

Comment: thats just bad design i would say...

Comment: Okay it does not follow normalization. but is there any way to get same answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should avoid storing data as comma-separated values, and follow normalization.

However in this case you can do something as

```
select 
e.id , 
e.name , 
group_concat(d.name) from employee e 
left join department d on find_in_set(d.id,e.department) 
group by e.id ;
```

Comment: Great response!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT replace(replace(department,'1','CS'),'2','IT')  as dept  from Employee
```

Comment: In the question, I believe just as an example the department table was shown with 2 records. With the solution you have provided, each time a record is added / modified in the department table, you will need to add / modify the replace statements

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's 

long-term value.